# Remove href link from images with overlay

Tags: wordpress, css

I need to turn the products listed in http://srougi.biz/gb/portfolio_listing/ into non-clickable items, but without loose its overlay effect. And since its a wordpress site, that I can't change the code, my only option is do it with CSS. I've tried to put pointer-events:none and cursor:default in the image, but it lost its overlay effect. I will appreciate your help.

Comment: can you use JavaScript?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To deactivate the links in this case, you need to add some javascript code.

**JS:** Add this before `</body>` in the theme file: `footer.php`

```
<script>
    var thumbnails = document.getElementsByClassName('thumbnail');
    for(i = 0; i < thumbnails.length; i++){
        thumbnails[i].getElementsByTagName("a")[0].setAttribute("onclick", "return false;");
    }
</script>
```

**CSS:** Style to remove pointer from link.

```
.thumbnail a {
    cursor: default !important;
}
```

Comment: Worked perfectly! Thank you so much, hallaji!

Answer (score 1):

we don't have  a option to handle the events in css.  use this jquery snippet to fix
$('.isotope-item .thumbnail a').click(function(e)  e.preventDefault();
});